# bitmapData to base64 and then to html tag img with src containing base64 encoded data

Tags: image, actionscript-3, actionscript, base64

i'm trying to get a snapshot from my cam. i have this part of code (as3) for a snapshot

```
        private static const encodeChars:Array = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','/'];

        private function snap():String{
                var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myVideo.width, myVideo.height);
                bitmapData.draw(myVideo);
                return encodeByteArray(bitmapData);
        }

        public static function encodeByteArray(data:BitmapData):String{  
                    if(data == null)throw new Error("data parameter can not be empty!");  
                    var bytes:ByteArray = data.getPixels(data.rect);  
                    bytes.writeShort(data.width);  
                    bytes.writeShort(data.height);  
                    bytes.writeBoolean(data.transparent);  
                    bytes.compress(); 
                    var out:Array = [];
                    var i:int = 0;
                    var j:int = 0;
                    var r:int = bytes.length % 3;
                    var len:int = bytes.length - r;
                    var c:int;
                    while (i < len) {
                        c = bytes[i++] << 16 | bytes[i++] << 8 | bytes[i++];
                        out[j++] = encodeChars[c >> 18] + encodeChars[c >> 12 & 0x3f] + encodeChars[c >> 6 & 0x3f] + encodeChars[c & 0x3f];
                    }
                    if (r == 1) {
                        c = bytes[i++];
                        out[j++] = encodeChars[c >> 2] + encodeChars[(c & 0x03) << 4] + "==";
                    }
                    else if (r == 2) {
                        c = bytes[i++] << 8 | bytes[i++];
                        out[j++] = encodeChars[c >> 10] + encodeChars[c >> 4 & 0x3f] + encodeChars[(c & 0x0f) << 2] + "=";
                    }
                    return out.join('');
        }
```

after i call it from js i'm creating an img tag inside my html and pasting received data into src attribute of img with the string "data:image/jpeg;base64," before. however i've got a broken icon of my browser. what do i do wrong and how to create an image using base64 encoded data from my cam?

thanks fo your help!

Comment: can you post your `encodeChars`?

Comment: yeap, i've just put them in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing it this way...

First you will need to grab the [Base64 SWC here](http://www.sociodox.com/base64.html) (right-click & save the red text, and come back here). If you need help to install an SWC you can check my other [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843663/as3-pngencoder-error/24845470#24845470). (You will also need that AS3 Corelib mentioned there if you dont already have the AS3 JPEG Encoder installed. AS3 Corelib takes care of encoding true JPG or PNG images from your raw bitmap data)

In code: You need **public** variables to store the image data bytes & string and also update them between snapshot function and base64 encoding functions etc.. So in this example code **actual_IMG** is actual image data (complete with jpeg header) ready to base64 or just save as regular .jpg to disk using `fileReference`.

```
public var actual_IMG:ByteArray = new ByteArray;
public var image_B64_str:String = new String;

private function snap():void
{
    var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(myVideo.width, myVideo.height);
    bitmapData.draw(myVideo);

    var jpg_Quality:int= 100;
    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(jpg_Quality);  

    actual_IMG = jpgEncoder.encode(bitmapData);
    encode_Image(); //do base64 encode function

}

private function encode_Image():void
{
    image_B64_str = Base64.encode(actual_IMG); //update string with b64 data
    doSomeFunction(); //do whatever is needed with.. image_B64_str (JPG string)
}

private function doSomeFunction():void
{
    //example: send "image_B64_str" to Javascript or save to disk etc etc...
}
```

Hope it helps..

**Update with direct links:**

- Base64 Encoder/Decoder SWC = http://www.sociodox.com/base64.html
- JPG/PNG Encoder = https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib
- How to install SWC in your project = [as3 PNGEncoder error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24843663/as3-pngencoder-error/24845470#24845470)

Comment: PS: If you do use that SWC make sure you haven't got another Base64 Encoder class imported to avoid any compiler errors

Comment: Can you not see that some texts in the answer are also links? They are blue coloured and will underline when you roll mouse over them... "`Base64 SWC here`" links to the SWC.. "see my `answer here`" has links for JPG/PNG encoder and gives setup instructions.. I'll update the answer anyways

Answer (score 2):

I believe the issue was with the way you are initially creating the `ByteArray` from the `BitmapData`. Flash has built-in encoding, I suggest you use it:

```
public static function encodeByteArray(data:BitmapData):String{  
    if(data == null)throw new Error("data parameter can not be empty!");  
    var bytes:ByteArray = data.encode(data.rect, new JPEGEncoderOptions(100));  //100 is the JPG quality
    var out:Array = [];
    var i:int = 0;
    var j:int = 0;
    var r:int = bytes.length % 3;
    var len:int = bytes.length - r;
    var c:int;
    while (i < len) {
        c = bytes[i++] << 16 | bytes[i++] << 8 | bytes[i++];
        out[j++] = encodeChars[c >> 18] + encodeChars[c >> 12 & 0x3f] + encodeChars[c >> 6 & 0x3f] + encodeChars[c & 0x3f];
    }
    if (r == 1) {
        c = bytes[i++];
        out[j++] = encodeChars[c >> 2] + encodeChars[(c & 0x03) << 4] + "==";
    }
    else if (r == 2) {
        c = bytes[i++] << 8 | bytes[i++];
        out[j++] = encodeChars[c >> 10] + encodeChars[c >> 4 & 0x3f] + encodeChars[(c & 0x0f) << 2] + "=";
    }
    return out.join('');
}
```

Comment: You can test your results by pasting the result of `encodeByteArray` into the decoder found here: http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Comment: i've tried to use your part of code and i've got two errors (1046):  Error: Call to a possibly undefined method encode through a reference with static type flash.display:BitmapData and (1046):  Error: Call to a possibly undefined method JPEGEncoderOptions.

Comment: What version of the FlashPlayer are you targeting? `BitmapData.encode` and `JPEGEncoderOptions` are only available for 11.3 and newer.

Comment: i did the same as it said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363557/jpegencoderoptions-is-undefined but nothing seemed to work

Comment: The methods described on that page should have done the trick. Are you still getting the same errors?

Comment: Sorry, not sure where you can go from here. The code above works assuming you're able to use `BitmapData.encode` and `JPEGEncoderOptions`.